# How can we change the color/style of the toolbar options (copy/paste) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Have a look at the image below. I know we have a widget called ToolbarOptions, where you can specify the options. But how to change the style. And we can change the style easily on editable text. But this is the text field.
Would love any help.

[image: see the image below]

Answer (score 2):

`surface` and `onSurface` properties did it for me

```
theme: ThemeData(
  colorScheme: ColorScheme(
   surface: Colors.green,
   onSurface: Colors.white
 ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing text selection color, you can use textSelectionTheme

cursorColor for the cursor line

selectionHandleColor for the bubble below the cursor

selectionColor for the highlight color

```
textSelectionTheme: _theme.textSelectionTheme.copyWith(
        cursorColor: AppColors.purple,
        selectionHandleColor: AppColors.purple,
        selectionColor: AppColors.grey4,
 ),
```

For changing text toolbarOption style, you can use button textTheme

```
textTheme: _theme.textTheme
          .copyWith(
            button: _theme.textTheme.button?.copyWith(
              //change it in this part
            ), 
          )
          .apply(fontFamily: GoogleFonts.roboto().fontFamily),
```

Comment: How do you change the context menu theme without changing the theme for all other buttons in the app?

Comment: copyWith method does the job. To do so just call (textTheme.headline1.copyWith(color: Colors.yourColor))